# While decrypting string using "AesManaged", getting the Padding is invalid and cannot be removed Exception in C#

Tags: c#, aes

Using this method  `string GetfunddtlsEncrypted_res = TradeSmartGetFundDetails(uid, uid);` I'm able to fetching the encrypted string

```
GetfunddtlsEncrypted_res = "1pGUvzzwv3Pg4O\/ZE6f8WSkkSWzymOZ4cBIVd\/ZkLC\/kCuZ9xkebaSB7htxDpcJSjGYe5eliUQIJrQaskpviN2E+uTN0EsC3tFd1h5QaIrTEz0vGIew16N33ecZo7oYNWmgR9aMp4BaZUDeqX3sVVg=="
```

After successfully fetch the above string I'm decoding using this method

```
 if (!(GetfunddtlsEncrypted_res.Contains("\"status\":false")))
                {
                    var Getfunddtlsdecryptedstr = DecryptPasswordAes(GetfunddtlsEncrypted_res);

                    TSGetFundDetails tSGetFundDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TSGetFundDetails>(Getfunddtlsdecryptedstr);

                }
```

Method Logic is :

```
 public string DecryptPasswordAes(string encryptedString)
        {
            //Convert cipher text back to byte array
            //byte[] cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);

            string strKey = "000fk15pvbbgmxgpej53298iu8nv555k";
            //string iv = "000fk15pvbbgmxgpej53298iu8nv555k";
            string iv = "7894561235789456";

            encryptedString = encryptedString.Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"", "");

//1pGUvzzwv3Pg4O/ZE6f8WSkkSWzymOZ4cBIVd/ZkLC/kCuZ9xkebaSB7htxDpcJSjGYe5eliUQIJrQaskpviN2E+uTN0EsC3tFd1h5QaIrTEz0vGIew16N33ecZo7oYNWmgR9aMp4BaZUDeqX3sVVg==

            //Convert cipher text back to byte array
            byte[] cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an AesManaged object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
            {
                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                aesAlg.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strKey);
                aesAlg.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
                // Create the streams used for decryption.

                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd(); // Exception {Padding is invalid and cannot be removed}
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return plaintext;

        }
```

At the end of this line `StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)` I'm getting the padding error.

Suggest me where I did the mistake and how can to achieve this.

Comment: `aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;` -- well that's wrong. You *need* padding with block ciphers like AES.

Comment: @canton7 thank you for your comment.

I  used  the below code and still getting the same error  

`aesAlg.BlockSize = 256;aesAlg.KeySize = 128;aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; `

Can you suggest me on this

Comment: You need to find out what parameters were used to encrypt that message